# Need help to push 8k column value from R into CLOB column(Oracle)

Tags: r, oracle

I am trying to push 8k characters in a single column along with 100k records into a Oracle table. This column with 8k characters is the 9th column and it was throwing an error asking me to push the column to the end. After doing so,I am still facing the below error:

```
 Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt, data = value) : 
  ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Please note that I have used CLOB as the data type for all columns in the table and "Factor" is the default data type in R.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pravellika J

Comment: Some sample data and the result you hope to achieve would help here.

Comment: How about `df[,c('V1','V3','V4','V2')]`?

Comment: I did try that, but the problem is when I write into DB, it still writes V2 into the 2nd column and not into the last column.

Comment: Why is the order of columns important here? This smells like the XY problem.

Comment: Basically i am importing 1000 log files reading them into a data frame and writing into a oracle table. But the problem is, there is one column value which has 8k characters. And when I insert this data frame into Oracle, it is expecting this column (with 8k records) to be at the end.(As it is a CLOB). So i am trying to push this to the end of the data table. But still end up with an error: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: I am confused by your question title. In your example it looks like you want to reorder both column data and column names---just like normal.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was mine. There were some more CLOB columns in the database and hence it was causing the trouble. I had to manually identify and make changes.