# Writing an R dataset to Oracle with very large fields (8000 char)

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I need to write an R dataset to an Oracle database using R package ROracle version 1.3-1, R version 3.4.1, Oracle OraClient 11g home and am new to R.

The dataset included variables of several different data types and lengths, including several **character type** up to 8000 characters long.

Using dbWriteTable

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "OracleTableName", df)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in .oci.WriteTable(conn, name, value, row.names = row.names, 
overwrite = overwrite,  : 
  Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt, data = value) : 
  ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

or this

```
Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt) : 
  ORA-02263: need to specify the datatype for this column
```

or this

```
drv <- 
  dbDriver("Oracle")
 conn <- 
  dbConnect(
     drv, 
    username = "username", 
    password = "password", 
    dbname = "dbname")
test.df1 <- subset(
  df, select=c(
    Var, Var2, Var3, 
    Var4, Var5, Var6))
dat <- as.character(test.df1)
attr(dat, "ora.type") <- "clob"
dbWriteTable(conn, "test2", dat)
```

returns this

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for 
signature ‘"OraConnection", "character", "character"’
```

From researching the error, it appears that the first error is indicating that the larger fields - BLOB fields - are not being recognized as BLOB by Oracle.

Documentation indicates that ROracle version 1.3-1 should be able to handle larger datatypes. It suggests using attribute to map NCHAR, CLOB, BLOB, NCLOB columns correctly in dbWriteTable. I have not been able to follow this example successfully as I keep getting the same error. Perhaps I just need a different example than that provided in the documentation?

Initially, I was using the RODBC package, but found that it's known that RODBC does not handle large datatypes (BLOB).

Any assistance or advice is appreciated.

Comment: did you look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542487/need-help-to-push-8k-column-value-from-r-into-clob-columnoracle)?

Comment: They say they fixed the problem, but do not indicate precisely how. I need the how, preferrably with code as I am new to R.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you're setting up the data frame, or where you're getting your example documentation from? I just found this example, which seems pretty comprehensive. https://rdrr.io/cran/ROracle/man/dbReadTable-methods.html#heading-7

Comment: This is the example I am referring to. As stated, I have attempted to follow it and am coming up with the same error. Further explanation or another example would be appreciated.

Comment: Contacted package creator and was able to write to an already created table on Oracle server. Still not able to create a table containing CLOB/BLOB variables.